# You Are Mine­­­

Tags: riddle, rhyme

I've hexed you so you'll get this wrong,
But you still cannot resist,
E-Y-R-I-E, that is correct,
Even as I tie your feet and wrists.

You're amazed when I'm around,
Destroy kid's dreams in D.C.,
I was there with your first crush,
10 letters in life you should keep.

Hint:

> Google not required and <s>one line *almost* qualifies as a red herring</s>, not anymore. The title could be helpful but is a personal thought I will be happy to share later - if someone doesn't read my mind first!

Hint 2:

> Google not required.  But if you're not from the United States you *might* not know about my connection to D.C., but you know *of* this clue.

Comment: I've fixed the title for you - feel free to roll it back.

Comment: You are Min? Does the e roll over to xtra?

Comment: @Deusovo, wasn't sure what happened! Said something about phantom characters so I used this instead. Didn't know it was being adjusted. Thank you sir.

Comment: @Areeb, just some typographical stuff going on.

Comment: @John: I used MathJax, the plugin we have for rendering math. `\vphantom{}` just makes something that has the height of the characters in the box, but no width - normally it's used for lining up math expressions, but it can also work to get around the title limit.

Comment: @Deusovo, cool, I'm on Android and it rendered as 'phantom'. I thought my own characters created an issue. Please feel free to adjust.

Comment: @Deusovo, perfect.

Comment: Does DC refer to [DC comics](https://www.dccomics.com)?

Comment: @ABcDexter, no the capitol. Revamping that line.

Comment: What does tossing people out of windows have to do with WDC?

Comment: @Mithrandir What does tossing *your crush* out of windows have to do with WDC?

Comment: @Mithandir, nothing.

Comment: @John A.) That didn't ping me, as you added a comma. 2.) Defenestration and Washing DC in the same riddle? :P

Comment: @Mithrandir thanks for the tip. Hint changes forthcoming.

Comment: @Deusovi, I was misspelling your name.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: wow, I think this is the most edits I've seen on a puzzle so far. Is "E-Y-R-I-E" a Game of Thrones reference?

Comment: @whrrgarbl Well, just trying to refine it. I believe the last edit was pretty helpful. Unfortunately it is not a Game of Thrones reference. And there will be no further edits. Glad to see someone is working on it.

Comment: @John that's actually good news for me since I don't watch GoT :D

Comment: @whrrgarbl, I do (because everyone else in the house makes it so...), but didn't know this word until I was putting together clues for a different puzzle. (puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/37833/ill-see-you-first). At that point, I saw that it was also a prison in that show, but I must have not seen those episodes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My answer is

> Spellbound

I've hexed you so you'll get this wrong,
But you still cannot resist,

> Hex and **spell** could be synonymous and we are **bound** to get this wrong because we are **spellbound**.

E-Y-R-I-E, that is correct,

> This is **spelling** out the word Eyrie (we could potentially argue that we are defining a **bound** Boolean variable). It also seems like the Eyrie could be a location in a Fantasy novel, entitled *Spellbound* (a Google search gives on such fairytale romance by Shirley Barber).

Even as I tie your feet and wrists.

> If your feet and wrists are tied, you are **bound**

You're amazed when I'm around,

> Spellbound.

Destroy kid's dreams in D.C.,

> I think this is in reference to the documentary film **Spellbound** which followed a group of children competing in the Scripps National Spelling Bee in Washington D.C.

I was there with your first crush,

> You could say you are spellbound in your first crush.

10 letters in life you should keep.

> Spellbound is ten letters long.

**Title**

> To spellbind is to hold the complete attention of someone, as if by magic, i.e, "You are Mine".

Comment: Very nice @hexomino. Of course, everything's covered well (beyond my own intended depth even). Good stuff!

Comment: I think the D.C./Scripps spelling bee reference still works without the documentary, don't you?